# Extend NHibernate Linq Provider

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate

Might anybody provide some example in order to extend Hibernate Linq Provider for asking for `whichever field [equals | lt | gt | notEquals ...] some_value`. I.e:

```
this.session.Query<C>.Where(c => c.WhichEverField().Equals(1));
```

where `WhichEverField()` would be an extension method.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a class I once wrote which allows you to use Convert.ToInt64() in a query:

```
public class ConvertToInt64HqlGenerator : BaseHqlGeneratorForMethod
{
    public ConvertToInt64HqlGenerator()
        : base()
    {
        this.SupportedMethods = new[] { ReflectionHelper.GetMethodDefinition(() => Convert.ToInt64("")),
                                        ReflectionHelper.GetMethodDefinition(() => Convert.ToInt64(0)),
                                        ReflectionHelper.GetMethodDefinition(() => Convert.ToInt64(0M))};
    }

    public override HqlTreeNode BuildHql(MethodInfo method,
                                            Expression targetObject,
                                            ReadOnlyCollection<Expression> arguments,
                                            HqlTreeBuilder treeBuilder,
                                            IHqlExpressionVisitor visitor)
    {
        return treeBuilder.Cast(visitor.Visit(arguments[0]).AsExpression(),typeof(Int64));
    }
}
```

To use it you need to create a Registry class:

```
public class MyLinqToHqlGeneratorsRegistry : DefaultLinqToHqlGeneratorsRegistry
{
    public MyLinqToHqlGeneratorsRegistry()
        : base()
    {
        this.Merge(new ConvertToInt64HqlGenerator());
    }
}
```

And add it to your configuration:

```
Fluently.Configure().Database(msSQLconfig)
                    .ExposeConfiguration(c => c.LinqToHqlGeneratorsRegistry<MyLinqToHqlGeneratorsRegistry>())
```

Answer (score 1):

You may check out among this [list](/a/11469134/1178314) if any of those extensions possibilities allows you to meet your goal.

But I doubt this is doable, if I have correctly understood your question. I do not know of any db syntax handling "whichever column" semantic, so I do not see how could it be possible to convert a `LINQ` extension having such a semantic to a SQL query having it too (which would moreover require a `HQL` extension since [linq-to-nhibernate](/questions/tagged/linq-to-nhibernate) works by converting the `LINQ` query to `HQL`).

If you intend to handle that semantic directly in your `LINQ` extension by generating a many `or` comparison criteria inside it, it does not look possible to me either with your proposed `c.WhichEverField().Equals(1)`.
Not only you would then have to use something like [AlexDev answer](/a/36983067/1178314). But also you will have to do type inspection on arguments and non trivial `HqlTree` building inside the `BuildHql` method.
And then, it will fail, because at the point  where the `BuildHql` method would be called for your `WhichEverField` extension as you have defined it, you will have no idea of which comparison have to be done on your operands.

Maybe with a `c.WhichEverField(SomeComparisonTypeEnum.Equal, 1)` extension, you could handle that, but that will not be an easy feat anyway.
If this may help, you can find more extension examples (from me) [here](/a/36211132/1178314) and by following the other links there, but none of them have the level of complexity of your demand.